# Access forbidden when trying to create segment from an existing list (Sendgrid v3 API C#)

Tags: c#, api, sendgrid, contacts

According to the V3 Sendgrid documentation, I can create segment (on a contact list) using API:
https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts-api-segments/create-a-segment#teconsent

My code is as follows:

```
        public static async void addSegment(SendGridClient client, string list_Id)
        {
            var data = @"{
                ""name"": ""location1"",
                ""list_id"": ""[MY_LIST_ID]"",
                ""conditions"": [
                    {
                        ""field"": ""Location"",
                        ""value"": ""location_1"",
                        ""operator"": ""eq"",
                        ""and_or"": """"
                    },
                ],
            }";

            var response = await client.RequestAsync(
                method: SendGridClient.Method.POST,
                urlPath: "contactdb/segments",
                requestBody: data
            );

            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
        }
```

However, I got the following error message:

*Forbidden*

*{"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"access forbidden"}]}*

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: shouldnt you be sending them some type of api key in the post?

Comment: And is there a reason you aren't reaching out to Sendgrid support for this?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I did. The client I created allowed me to create contacts and contact lists with no issues

Comment: @DavidL I did, but so far I got no response, and I'm not sure if I'm the one making the mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

[SendGrid API keys](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys) can be scoped to only permit certain actions against the API. My guess here is that the API key you are using does not have permission to create a segment on the contact list.

You could either use an API key with full access or ensure the key you are using has access to (I think) the marketing APIs.

Comment: Hi, my sendgrid API key is Full access. Note that I can create contacts and contact lists with no issues. In addition, please note that my account is Free tier. Is that the reason why?

Comment: The API you link to is for the legacy marketing campaigns product, are you using the latest marketing campaigns iteration and should you be using the [segmenting contacts API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/segmenting-contacts/create-segment)?

Comment: yes you are right. When using Sendgrid V3, I need to pay attention to not use any legacy API